# Rewrite specific subdomain to https

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to get some images working through a CDN which is setup as a CNAME to point to a specific URL which then catches my assets.

Right now I'm working on my stage server. I am needing to only rewrite stage.domain.com to https and leave the cdn.domain.com intact.

```
    # Force to HTTPS
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com [NC]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://stage.domain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

However, when I use this, it catches the cdn.domain.com and rewrites that as well. How can I specify to ignore that URL?

Comment: `^domain\.com` matches neither `stage.domain.com` nor `cdn.domain.com`.

Comment: _"I am needing to only rewrite stage.domain.com to https and leave the cdn.domain.com intact"_ - that doesn't make the most sense either, if you are planning to embed external resources from the CDN domain into the HTML document loaded from the staging domain via HTTPS, because it will cause the browser to issue loads of mixed content warnings, and it might even block certain resources.